# Embed images from Google search results (for free)

Tags: google-search-api

I understand Google Custom Search now replaces previous search API's (examples with images found on stackoverflow are now obsolete), so I enabled images in GCS for my website, but I only want to display 5 images corresponding to a specific keyword (and not have the user enter his own query), and chose my own CSS style for these images (size, border)...

I see Bing also offers an API, which won't be free (despite the fact that I usually only get a few hundreds visitors per day, bots are hitting hard and sometimes a few thousands visits come from FB or elsewhere, so I don't want to take any risk with a pay on demand solution !)

Any advice to configure cse.google.com (or other API !) to show the first 5 images from Google image search on my pages, maybe with a link to the url of the original image, or larger version on Google images ?

All I have now is this code from GCS :

"To implement a stand-alone search results page, paste the results code snippet into your results page:"

```
<script>
(function() {
  var cx = 'YOUR_ENGINE_ID';
  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
  gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

"Now you can trigger search results on this page by passing a "q" argument in the url:"

http://my-results-page-url.com/?q=myQuery

It displays images only with `disableWebSearch=TRUE` the issues are 1. I don't see how to make this extra layer fit into my own layout, 2. I don't need that searchbox !